# How to append values to specific lists after a for loop?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of temperatures that I am trying to group into four different lists: cold, slippery, comfortable, warm.

Here is my code:

```
#temperatures list
temperatures = [-5.4, 1.0, -1.3, -4.8, 3.9, 0.1, -4.4, 4.0, -2.2, -3.9, 4.4,
                -2.5, -4.6, 5.1, 2.1, -2.4, 1.9, -3.3, -4.8, 1.0, -0.8, -2.8,
                -0.1, -4.7, -5.6, 2.6, -2.7, -4.6, 3.4, -0.4, -0.9, 3.1, 2.4,
                1.6, 4.2, 3.5, 2.6, 3.1, 2.2, 1.8, 3.3, 1.6, 1.5, 4.7, 4.0,
                3.6, 4.9, 4.8, 5.3, 5.6, 4.1, 3.7, 7.6, 6.9, 5.1, 6.4, 3.8,
                4.0, 8.6, 4.1, 1.4, 8.9, 3.0, 1.6, 8.5, 4.7, 6.6, 8.1, 4.5,
                4.8, 11.3, 4.7, 5.2, 11.5, 6.2, 2.9, 4.3, 2.8, 2.8, 6.3, 2.6,
                -0.0, 7.3, 3.4, 4.7, 9.3, 6.4, 5.4, 7.6, 5.2]
#Lists to store different temperatures
cold = []
slippery = []
comfortable = []
warm = []

#Assign values to respective temperature lists
for temp in temperatures:
    if temp < -2:
        cold = []
        cold. append(temp)
    elif temp >= -2 and temp < 2:
        slippery = []
        slippery. append(temp)
    elif temp >= 2 and temp < 15:
        comfortable = []
        comfortable. append(temp)
    elif temp >= 15:
        warm = []
        warm. append(temp)

print(cold)
print(slippery)
print(comfortable)
print(warm)
```

Here is my output. Instead of having four lists, I got only one output for each list.

```
[-4.6]
[-0.0]
[5.2]
[]
```

How do a append a list of values to each list based on the criteria above? Forgive me if this is a silly question. I started learning Python so I'd appreciate any insights.
Thank you!

Comment: You reset your list to an empty list every time before appending.

Comment: Don't re-initialize the lists inside the loop.

Comment: I understand my mistake now. Thanks so much! As I reset my list to an empty list, why did the output list have one random value? What was going on behind the code? @Barmar

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Step through with a debugger and keep an eye on each variable you're interested in. It'll be pretty obvious what happens and why

Comment: It's not one random value, it's the last value you put in each list.

Comment: Each time you append to a list, you first empty it. So at the end you get the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reset the list everytime :) Hope this helps!

```
for temp in temperatures:
    if temp < -2:
        cold.append(temp)
    elif temp >= -2 and temp < 2:
        slippery.append(temp)
    elif temp >= 2 and temp < 15:
        comfortable.append(temp)
    elif temp >= 15:
        warm.append(temp)
```